# Standard Objects and External Id

Tags: standard-objects, externalid

Has any **standard object** an **external id** by default ?

I need to know it for testing proposes.

I was searching this unsuccessfully.

Comment: As a semi-aside, there is a very useful custom object in the Apex-Lang package, called "Foo", that contains fields of the major field types (not including external ID, actually, but you could add it) for the sole purpose of unit tests. It's very useful since there are quite a few field types that aren't on the out-of-the-box objects.

Comment: I didn't know about that. thanks you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

External Ids are by definition for mapping to an external system typically in data migration / integration scenarios. So there aren't any out of the box external ids, but you can use the Salesforce Id for upsert operations too.

Equally it is quite simple to create a text field and mark it as an external Id. You can create upto 3 external Id fields per sObject.

Comment: Thank you > "So there aren't any out of the box external ids", that is the answer I was looking for. Don't ask me why, but I don't have permission to create an external id in the org that I'm working. However, In order to test something I need any object which contains that type of field. Never mind, I'll try to bypass this. Thx again.